# One page dot navigation that misses out the middle sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

It's hard to explain the effect I want and the only place I have seen this navigation so far is on the tumblr login/home page: https://www.tumblr.com/

It scrolls down a section on mouse scroll similar to this: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ but manages to miss out the sections in between anchors when the dot navigation is used. So using the navigation you can scroll straight from dot 1 to dot 5 without scrolling past dot 2, 3 and 4. And it maintains the scrolling effect rather than jumping down to the 5th anchor.

I'm not sure whether it would be best to try and load the content of the next div/iframe dynamically depending where the user is on the site or have all the divs laid out and just move them around with css depending on where the user is currently on the site.

If anyone has any ideas that would be great, thanks for your time

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/alvarotrigo/pagePiling.js?utm_source=jquer.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation

Comment: you can hide the dots(sections) between the curent dot and the dot that is selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Barbara Laird, you should be using [pagePiling.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling) to achieve that same effect.